# Designing a dynamic template

Tags: templates, design-patterns, dynamic, data-modeling

I am designing a laboratory system for an alloy steel company, in this system we have
some type of tests(e.g Analysis Test, Impact Test, ...) must be apply on each product in production line, I used the `TestTemplate` class for define each test type template(e.g Analysis test template). 
Each test type, has some parameter and each parameter could be in form of:

- Ranged values (min,max)
- Single value (value)
- Selectable value (one or more value selected from a values list)

*(till now, and in future may find some new parameter types).*

Also for each production we should define some nominal values for each test type template( in the other word desired values for each test type template), for example for productA the nominal values for the analysis test could be as below:

- Carbon range: (Min=0.23 Max=0.65)
- Fe range: (Min=1.25 Max=1.75)
- Cu range: (Min=0.87 Max=1.02)

and for ProductB the nominals could be as:

- Carbon range: (Min=0.43 Max=0.55)
- Fe range: (Min=1.15 Max=1.65)
- Cu range: (Min=0.57 Max= 1.12)
- Pb range: (value = 0.12) /* single value type parameter*/

And this is my design for this problem
[image]

**Main goal of my design is to achieve a dynamic structure for the test templates**, is there any design pattern or some best practices for this case, or is this design good, enough?

Comment: What do mean exactly by "achieve a dynamic structure for the test templates" ?

Comment: @Sniffer: I mean that a power user could define a new test template, with composition of different type of parameters, and then other users could create some nominal test values based on that newly created test template.

Answer (score 3):

I congratulate you with your design. This design has a very clear distinction between class and instance and is not bad at all.

Your question is unclear. What do you think is wrong with your design or needs improvement? Sometimes asking the right question is what will give you the right answer.

One thing I would have improved upon is the TestParameter class. I'd probably have generalized that. In other words, I would have made a RangeTestParameter, SingleValueTestParameter and a SelectableTestParameter. I would've made that generalized TestParameter include a factory method too:

```
ITestParameterValue ITestParameter.createValue()
```

Implemented by SelectableParameter it would return a SelectableValue. That SelectableValue would have been supplied with a set of selectable/permitted values via its constructor.

This way you could address two points in your design that triggered questions I would have asked myself if this was my design:

1. TestParameterType: Why design a type class when the type is available to you at compile-time? How are you going to ensure that your Code parameter contains a valid and functional value? Who is responsible for creating these types based upon these Codes?
2. PermitedValue: Does TestParameter have a list of ParameterValues only if the TestParameter has a (Code) reference to the ParameterType Selectable? What if it doesn't? Who ensures it does? Who knows how to interpret a TestParameter in this particular way? Only SelectableValue? Only those who have read the if statement in your class diagram?

If you'd like to present your users with a list of possible parameters you can create a TestParameterFactory that links your parameter types to some additional info. Here is a simple Java version of such a factory:

```
public class TestParameterFactory {
    private final Map<String, ITestParameter.class> parameterTypes;

    public TestParameterFactory() {
        parameterTypes = new HashMap<String, ITestParameter.class>();
        parameterTypes.put("Range", RangeTestParameter.class);
        parameterTypes.put("Selectable", SelectableTestParameter.class);
        parameterTypes.put("Single value", SingleValueTestParameter.class);
    }

    public getParameterTypes() {
        return parameterTypes;
    }

    public ITestParameter createParameter(String name) {
        ITestParameter parameterType = parameterTypes.get(name);
        if (parameterType == null) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name+ " is not a valid parameter type name");
        return parameterType.newInstance();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mrhobo, first, you said : "Implemented by SelectableParameterValue it would return a SelectableValue. That SelectableValue would have been supplied with a set of selectable/permitted values via its constructor." I don't understand it very well, could you explain it more please? second, if i don't use TestParameterType class, when a power user wants to define a new test template, how can i show him type of acceptable test parameter types for a test?

Comment: Made a mistake. I meant "implemented by SelectableParameter" not "SelectableParameterValue". I corrected it. SelectableParameter is a type of TestParameter which can construct a new ITestParameterValue (same as NominalTestParameter) object. The factory method on the SelectableParameter passes the SelectableParameterValue a list of permitted values at construction time.

Comment: To answer your second question: using a factory that hold the information about the types. See my updated answer.